# Illegal string offset 'name' CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a new user of CodeIgniter 4. I got this error when I want to show 'prodi_name' of table 'prodi' on a form.

This is my ProdiModel

```
protected $table = 'prodi';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_prodi';

public function getProdi($id = false)
{
    if ($id == false) {
        return $this->findAll();
    }
    return $this->where('prodi_code', $id)->first();
}
```

I have setting my BaseController with

```
$this->prodiModel = new \App\Models\ProdiModel();
```

so my Controller is

```
public function add()
{
    $data = [
        'title'     => 'Admin',
        'prodi'     => $this->prodiModel->getProdi(),
        'validation' => \Config\Services::validation()
    ];

    return view('admin/add', $data);
}
```

And this is my form, I want to show the prodi_name on a multiple select field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Prodi</label>
    <select class="form-control select2 multiple" id="prodi" name="prodi[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select prodi">
     <?php
     foreach ($prodi as $prodi) :
         echo "<option value='" . $prodi["prodi_name"] . "'";
         if (old('prodi')) {
            if (in_array($prodi['prodi_name'], old('prodi'))) echo "selected";
         }
         echo ">" . $prodi['prodi_name'] . "</option>";
     endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the code for the line that generates that error.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in CI 4 there is no first() method,
use

```
public function getProdi($id = false)
{
    if ($id == false) {
        return $this->findAll();
    }
    return $this->where('prodi_code', $id)->getFirstRow(‘array’);
}
```

On the second thought you are returning two types of data here, if id is false you return multidimensional array and if id is there code returns single row.
Again in the same method, you have called findAll(), if it returns and associative array, your code should run, but if that returns a object then you should change to,

```
  <?php
     foreach ($prodi as $prodi) :
         echo "<option value='" . $prodi->prodi_name . "'";
         if (old('prodi')) {
            if (in_array($prodi->prodi_name, old('prodi'))) echo "selected";
         }
         echo ">" . $prodi->prodi_name . "</option>";
     endforeach; ?>
```